# Generate a random list that have 2 different ranges in 2 dimensions

Tags: random

Here is my  thing. Each element in the list has its own range.

`{RandomReal[{0, 1}], RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]}`

This code alone can only generate a point.  Is it possible to generate 10 random points?

`Transpose[{RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10], RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, 10]}]`

**I found this one that works  at the code above. Is there anyone who can achieve  that but much more  elegant than me?**

Comment: `{#, 2 Pi #2} & @@@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}]`?

Comment: The solution by @kglr is very slick. Let me just point out that it is also the most efficient, since producing all the `RandomReal`s in one go is highly optimized in Mathematica.

Comment: and  `ScalingTransform[{1, 2 Pi}] @ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}]`?

Comment: Ok, I was wrong. The more verbose `Function[{n}, Transpose[RandomReal[{0, #}, n] & /@ {1, 2 \[Pi]}]][10]` is 10 times faster than the `ScalingTransform` solution (and the first one @kglr posted is actually *really* inefficient.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `UniformDistribution` and you can have as many ranges as you want if you supply them in a matrix as the first argument:

```
RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 2 Pi}}], 10]
```

Comment: This is also the fastest out of all the methods mentioned in the comments so far but only when dealing with more than a hundred points. Otherwise, for tens of points it has similar performance.